# parametrising queries (Visual studio)

Tags: sql

I have a report that shows the Active vendors (v.blocked=0) only but I want to parametrise this so the I has the option to show the active vendors or All (both active and inactive)

Not sure if I've provided enough below.

```
ON v.Party = c.VendParty
where v.DataaReaid='CVS' AND V.Blocked=0
```

This is the full code.

```
--Vend
SELECT 
v.AccountNum    AS [Supplier number],
p.Name          AS [Supplier name],
STUFF((    SELECT ',' + E.Name AS [text()] -- Add a comma (,) before each value
                        FROM VendCategory SUB
                            INNER JOIN EcoResCategory E
                                ON SUB.Category = E.RecId
                        WHERE
                        SUB.VendorAccount = V.AccountNum
                        AND
                        SUB.VendorDataArea = V.DataAreaId
                        FOR XML PATH('') -- Select it as XML
                        ), 1, 1, '' ) -- This is done to remove the first character (,) from the result
                AS [Procurement categories],
v.Memo AS [Notes],
STUFF((    SELECT ',' + SUB.DataAreaId AS [text()] -- Add a comma (,) before each value
                        FROM vendTable SUB
                        WHERE
                        SUB.AccountNum = v.AccountNum
                        and v.Blocked = 0 
                        FOR XML PATH('') -- Select it as XML
                        ), 1, 1, '' ) --This is done to remove the first character (,) from the result
                AS [List of companies released to],
CASE WHEN o.ABC = 1 THEN 'A' WHEN o.ABC = 2 THEN 'B'  WHEN o.ABC = 3 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END AS [ABC Code],
v.PaymTermId    AS [Payment terms],
v.Currency      AS [Currency],
v.PaymMode      AS [Payment method],
v.CISCompanyRegNum    AS [Company Reg number],
C.CertificationType   AS [Certification of DD],
C.ValidFromDate       AS [Effective date],
C.ValidToDate       AS [Expiration date]
FROM VendTable V
LEFT JOIN 
    DirPartyTable P
        ON v.Party=p.recid
    LEFT JOIN DirOrganization O
    ON p.RecId =o.RecId
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT C.VendParty,MAX(C.CertificationType) AS CertificationType, MAX(C.ValidFromDate) AS ValidFromDate,MAX(C.ValidToDate) AS ValidToDate
    FROM vendCertification c
        INNER JOIN DirPartyTable i
            ON c.IssuerParty = i.RecID
            AND i.Name = 'Supplier Due Diligence'
    GROUP BY c.VendParty


) C
ON v.Party = c.VendParty
where v.DataaReaid='CVS' AND V.Blocked=0
```

Comment: What is the dbms you're using?  Also, you need to provide more information.  If you can't supply the entire query, create a sample query that is doing the same thing.

Comment: The square brackets around identifiers indicates that the database is Microsoft or Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the filter column as the parameter to the report procedure and simply call the procedure in the report with the filter column as the input parameter.

For example

```
create proc
@vblock int;

As
..
..
select ...
ON v.Party = c.VendParty
where v.DataaReaid='CVS' AND 
 where V.Blocked = @vblock
```